# Constructor for Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a JAvascript Object with a constructor and 2 methods. I am getting errors when I try to use the following code, what am I doing wrong? Specifically, it wont allow me to define the constructor function as shown below.

```
var Feed = {

    templateDOM: '',

    function(tDOM) {
        this.templateDOM = tDOM;
    },

    loadFeed: function(feedPage, feedsPerPage) {
        ...
    },

    showFeed: function(data, tDOM, destination) {
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: "it wont allow me to define the constructor function" — What do you mean "wont allow"? Do you get an error?

Comment: yes - my editor gives an error

Comment: The editor marks an error in the `function(tDOM)` method saying `:` expected

Comment: huh? why the downvote?

Comment: @MubashirHanif I did look up resources on the internet before posing this question. Ofcourse I didnt understand the concepts well to resolve my problem on my own. If we can only ask questions that cannot be resolved by all other resources on the internet then the purpose of StackOverflow is defeated... or so I would think

Comment: @ChicagoSky Dude.. no Hard Feelings.. But you should at least do some basic reading on internet about JS objects or these little things. We are obviously here to help. but you've to do your part of things as well.

Comment: @MubashirHanif none whatsoever. However I think there is room for newbie questions as well as complex questions. This probably falls in the former category. StackOverflow is a compilation of all such questions ... wouldnt you agree?

Comment: @ChicagoSky I agree to my fullest. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't creating a constructor function at all here. It is a plain object, only you forgot to provide a property name for the second value in it.

If you wanted to create a constructor function, it would look more like this:

```
function Feed(tDOM) {
    this.templateDOM = tDOM;
}

Feed.prototype.loadFeed = function loadFeed(feedPage, feedsPerPage) {
};

Feed.prototype.showFeed = function showFeed(data, tDOM, destination) {
};
```

Which you can then invoke like:

```
var my_feed = new Feed("some value");
myFeed.loadFeed("some value", "some other value");
```

Comment: Thank you - ofcourse looks like my grasp on JS objects needs a lot more work. But I thank you for taking the time to help

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you approach can take you where you want. In your case you make use of an object literal. How are you going to make use of constructor, when you have already created an object?

I think that the following would be more suitable:

```
// Define a cosntructor
function TemplateDom(tDom){
     this.templateDOM = tDOM;
}
```

and then add to the prototype of you constructor the methods:

```
// Add to the prototype of your constructor the following two functions.
// So each object that will be created using this constructor would have
// defined also those two methods.
TemplateDom.prototype.loadFeed = function(feedPage, feedsPerPage) {
    ...
};

TemplateDom.prototype.showFeed = function(data, tDOM, destination) {
    ...
};
```

Then you can create an object like below:

```
var templateDom = new TemplateDom("here you pass a dom value");
```

and you can use the functions `loadFeed` and `showFeed` as simple as

```
templateDom.loadFeed("feedpage value","feedsperpage value");
templateDom.showFeed("data value","tDom value","destination value");
```